# How do I declare multiple values for a 3D vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, declaration

I have the typedef `typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> three_d_vector;` to declare the 3D vector; but I want to know how, if I can, do I declare the individual values in a bulk list, like an array.

Comment: Are your values constants?

Comment: what do you mean "in a bulk list"? with C++11 you can use initializer lists, but not sure that's what you're asking for

Comment: Are you talking about an array of `three_d_vector`?

Comment: I imagine something like `vector<vector<vector<int> > > a = {{{1,2}, {3,4}, .....}}}`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: assuming he's using C++11, then yes, initializer list should do the job

Comment: If you don't have C++11, you can use boost's `assign::list_of`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile in C++11 mode (e.g. use the command-line switch `-std=c++11` for gcc) and use a syntax like this:

```
three_d_vector vec = { { {1., 2.}, {3.,  4., 17., 25.} },
                       { {5., 6., 12.}, {7.,  8.}, {0., 22.} },
                       { {9., 10.}, {11.}, {45.}, {33.}, {37., 11.} };
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working on C++11 and what you're asking for is a direct way to initialize your vector:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef vector<vector<vector<double>>> three_d_vector;

    three_d_vector v =
    {
        {
            { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }
        },
        {
            { 0, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 0 }
        },
        {
            { 4, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 5 }
        },
    };
}
```

However, please notice that defining a 3D vector this way will give you freedom to have different vector sizes for each dimension. In other words, this will be legal:

```
    three_d_vector v =
    {
        {
            { 1, 2, 3, 7 }, { 4, 5, 6 }
        },
        {
            { 0, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 0, 8, 9, 15 }
        },
        {
            { 4, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }
        },
    };
```

Whether this is desired, acceptable or unacceptable depends on your use case; anyway, I guess you might want to have a look at [**Boost.MultiArray**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` won't be very cache coherent. Use a [`Boost.MultiArray`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) instead.